# Unable to update the value in combobox to sheet

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I am new to VBA Coding.I have an userform which retrieves the value from excel sheet.There is a combobox which retrieves the value.But i want to change the combobox value & save it in excel.....

#### Image for Data in Excel

[image: Image for Data in Excel]

```
Dim temp As String
Dim findid As String
Dim lkrange As Range
Set lkrange = Sheet6.Range("A:D")

findid = TextBox1.Value

On Error Resume Next
temp = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(findid, lkrange, 1, 0)
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
MsgBox "ID not found"
Else
MsgBox "ID found"

Label5.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(findid, lkrange, 2, 0)
Label6.Caption = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(findid, lkrange, 3, 0)
ComboBox1.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(findid, lkrange, 4, 0)

End If

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim fid As String
Dim rowc As Integer
Dim rowv As Integer

fid = TextBox1.Value

rowc = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(fid, Range("A:A"), 0)
rowv = rowc - 1

Cells(rowv, 4).Values = marktable.ComboBox1.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

you could try the following

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim lkrange As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set lkrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A:A")

With Me

    Set rng = MyMatch(.TextBox1.Value, lkrange)

    If rng Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "ID not found"
    Else
        MsgBox "ID found"
        .Label5.Caption = rng.Offset(0, 1)
        .Label6.Caption = rng.Offset(0, 2)
        .ComboBox1.Text = rng.Offset(0, 3)
    End If

End With

End Sub


Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim lkrange As Range
Dim rng As Range

Set lkrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A:A")

With Me
    Set rng = MyMatch(.TextBox1.Value, lkrange)
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then rng.Offset(0, 3).Value = .ComboBox1.Text
End With

End Sub



Private Function MyMatch(val As Variant, rng As Range, Optional matchType As Variant) As Range
Dim row As Long

If IsMissing(matchType) Then matchType = 0

On Error Resume Next
row = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(val, rng, matchType)
If Err = 0 Then Set MyMatch = rng.Parent.Cells(rng.Rows(row).row, rng.Column)

End Function
```

there were some errors:

- `Sheet6.Range("A:D")` is not vaild

  if you want to point to a sheet named "Sheet6" belonging to the Workbook where the macro resides, then you have to use `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6").Range("A:A")`
- `Cells(...,...).Values =...` is not valid

  you must use `Cells(...,...).Value =`

but I think the following suggestions are more important:

- Always use `Option Explicit` statement at the very beginning of every module

  this will force you to explicitly declare each and every variable, but then it'll save you lots of time in debugging process
- avoid/limit the use of `On Error Resume Next` statement

  and, when used, make sure to have it followed as soon as possible by the "On Error GoTo 0" one. that way you have constant control on whether an error occurs and where

  I confined it in a "wrapper" function (MyMatch()) only.
- Always specify "full" references when pointing to a range

  I mean, `Cells(..,..)` implictly points to the active sheet cells, which may not always be the one you'd want to point to.